# Return location hierarchy from EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 tables that have the normal relationships you'd expect in, Region, District, Location. A location belongs to a district and a district belongs to a region. I bring these 3 tables into EF and the relationships are there (Region table has a property to Districts table).

Given the relationships are already there I'm looking for an easy query that would return all 3 relationships for a couple fields I want out of each table, so I can return that from my web api:

```
[{
   "region": "0",
   "name": "Test"
   [{
      "district": "0"
      "name": "Flower"
         [{
            "location": "0",
            "name": "What"
         }]
   }]
},
{
  ...etc
}]
```

Since there are a lot more fields in each, do I have to build the relationship in my own tables that just have these fields or can I only pick the fields I want from each table while keeping the relationship from the EF tables in one query? Ideally I'd like to do this in that query syntax as I find that more natural.

Comment: Just create a query with projections (`select`) to anonymous/specific types with the desired fields. Inside the query you could use the entity *navigation properties* if that's what you mean by relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to select fields that you need.

Like:

```
var results = dbContext.Regions.Select(r => new RegionModel{
   Id = r.Id,
   Name = r.Name
   Districts = r.Districts.Select(d => new DistrictModel {
    .......
   })
});
```

I suppose that RegionModel and DistrictModel is some data transfer object that will be used on upper abstraction layer (services, controller, etc. )

You can also use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to convert your entities to DTOs using [QueryableExtensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) this will do selects for you automatically based on your configuration.

**UPD:**

You can use LINQ query syntax as well:

```
var results = from r in dbContext.Regions select new RegionModel { 
    Id = r.Id, 
    Name = r.Name 
    Districts = from d in r.Districts select new DistrictModel {
     ...
    } 
});
```

Comment: Do I have to use the method syntax vs the query syntax for the inner lists (Districts in your example)?

Comment: You can use any syntax you want here.

Comment: var results = from r in  dbContext.Regions new RegionModel {
   Id = r.Id,
   Name = r.Name
   Districts = from d in r.Districts select new DistrictModel {}
});

Comment: Ah ok , I never nested from's like that before. Thank!

Comment: Do you have to do ToList or something on the Districts part? It doesn't seem to like that syntax.

Comment: Check your RegionModel.Districts type this should be IEnumerable<DistrictModel> then all will run ok